# User input boundary - Java

Tags: java, input

I'm quite new to programming. I am looking for a way to set a boundary for the user input variables. Here is a snippet of my code

```
   public static void main(String[] agrs){

   Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String angle;
    System.out.println("Angle:");
    angle = user_input.next();
```

For example, I would like the possible input to be only between 30 and 60 degrees.

Comment: You should look into basic Java tutorials about `if-else` blocks.

Comment: When you learn more Java, you will learn that you might want to throw an Exception here to indicate that the expected input is not correct for the function you are trying to execute

Comment: This looks like an interactive program and throwing an exception makes for unpleasant user experience. An alternative may be to print an error message that guides the user to provide a valid input without exiting.

Comment: It only needs to be something basic. If values are in the 30-60 range, then program will jump to the next question (in my case, will prompt the user to input a value for speed). If values are not within the 30-60 range, program should display an error message and prompt the user to enter a value again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
int angle = user_input.nextInt();
validateAngle( angle );
```

where the `validateAngle` method has your custom validation logic. `Scanner` will make sure that the input is an `int` (and will throw an exception otherwise) but you will have to provide the additional constraints yourself.

The following loops until a valid angle is provided:

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int angle = 0;
    while (invalidAngle(angle)) {
        angle = userInput.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: So if validation fails, then what?

Comment: That is a question to the OP. Perhaps you would like to add it as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

use if block to check input conditions like this,

```
 if(angle < 30 && angle > 60 ) {
  System.out.println("invalid input")
} else {
   doSomethingMeaningful();
}
```

Comment: Or, rather than print, throw an IllegalArgumentException. Probably way over the head of OP though

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using an if/then construct to validate user entries:

```
public class LargestAndSmallest {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    final Set<Integer> ints = new HashSet<>();
    int n;
    while ((n = keyboard.nextInt()) != -99) {
      if (valid(n)) {
        ints.add(n);
      }
      System.out.println("Enter more numbers, or -99 to quit.");
    }
    System.out.println("the largest is " + Collections.min(ints));
    System.out.println("the smallest is " + Collections.max(ints));
  }

  // Validation happens here
  private static boolean valid(final int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      System.out.println("Negative numbers (other than -99) are not allowed.");
      return false;
    } else if (n > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
      System.out.println("Your entry is too large.");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```